# Query regarding rowdatabound event in gridview asp.net/C#

Tags: asp.net, gridview

When u have a gridview(lets say gridview1) and u associate an event

```
OnRowDataBound = "gridView1_RowDatabound"
```

and u usually start the event method as follows

```
protected void gridView1_RowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){

      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
        do something..
      }

      }
```

Why do u have to check again if the row is data row, as i understand it gridview1_rowdatabound event occurs only when the rows are getting bound by the datasource u supplied. Why do u perform again this additional checking ?

Can u elucidate it for me ?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to be able to perform different actions based on the row type:

A row can be a '**header**' row or a normal '**data**' row for example.

The `DataControlRowType` enum gives you a pretty good idea what types of rows might appear:

```
public enum DataControlRowType
{
    Header,
    Footer,
    DataRow,
    Separator,
    Pager,
    EmptyDataRow
}
```

Comment: so if i remove the "if condition" then what ever i do in the rowdatabound event method would apply to all the rows irrespective of its type? Can i draw that inference from ur answer ?

Comment: @user653622 yes that should be the case